# SAS: Holt Winters Forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, sas

I have an estimate for the Holt-Winters model as the attached image. How do I interpret the estimates i.e. the level, trend and seasonal smoothing weight?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think these are the alpha, beta and gamma coefficient for the model. Basically the model is to be written as:

[image]

If you are asking the "meaning" behind these parameters, maybe the following link will help you.

[Interpretation of level, trend and seasonal indices in Holt-Winters exponential smoothing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193901/interpretation-of-level-trend-and-seasonal-indices-in-holt-winters-exponential)